# React redux separation of concerns

Tags: asynchronous, reactjs, q, redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to build a simple app to view photos posted from nasa's picture of the day service (https://api.nasa.gov/api.html#apod). Currently watching for keypresses, and then changing the date (and asynchronously the picture) based on the keypress being an arrow left, up, right, or down. These would correspondingly change the date represented by a week or a day (imagine moving across a calendar one square at a time).

What I'm having trouble with is this: I've created an async action creator to fetch the next potential date - however I need to know the current state of the application and the keypress to retrieve the new date. Is there a way to encapsulate this into the action creator? Or should I put the application state where the exported action creator is called in the application so I can keep my action creator unaware of the state of the application? I've tried to do this by binding the keydown function in `componentDidMount` for the top level `Component`, but the binding to the application store doesn't seem to reflect the changes that happen in the reducer.

The async logic relying on redux-thunk middleware and q:

```
// This function needs to know the current state of the application
// I don't seem to be able to pass in a valid representation of the current state
function goGetAPIUrl(date) {
   ...
}

function getAsync(date) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    return goGetAPIUrl(date).then(
      val => dispatch(gotURL(val)),
      error => dispatch(apologize(error))
    );
  };
}

export default function eventuallyGetAsync(event, date) {
  if(event.which == 37...) {
    return getAsync(date);
  } else {
    return {
      type: "NOACTION"
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the top level binding to the gridAppState, and other stuff that happens at top level that may be relevant that I don't quite understand.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { gridAppState, actions } = this.props;
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function() {
      actions.eventuallyGetAsync(event, gridAppState.date);
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { gridAppState, actions } = this.props;
    return (
        <GridApp gridAppState={gridAppState} actions={actions} />
    );
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  gridAppState: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    gridAppState: state.gridAppState
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(GridActions, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

I've validated that the correctly modified date object is getting to the reducer - however the gridAppState seems stuck at my initial date that is loaded.

What is the right way to approach async logic in redux that relies on attaching event handlers and current application state? Is there a right way to do all three?

Answer (score 2):

You should handle the event in your component and call the correct action depending on the key pressed.

So when you dispatch an async action you can do something like

```
export default function getNextPhoto(currentDate) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    const newDate = calculateNewDate(currentDate);

    dispatch(requestNewPhoto(newDate));

    return photosService.getPhotoOfDate(newDate)
    .then((response) => {
      dispatch(newPhotoReceived(response.photoURL);
    });
  };
}
```

You should handle the keypress event on the component and just dispatch your action when you know you need to fetch a new photo.

Your App would look like

```
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { gridAppState, actions } = this.props;
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function() {
      if (event.which == 37) {
        actions.getNextPhoto(gridAppState.date);
      } else if (...) {
        actions.getPrevPhoto(gridAppState.date);
      }

      // etc
    });
  }
}
```

By the way you re still missing your reducers that update your state in the Redux Store.

Comment: I don't actually think it matters where I process which keybinding there is, but I suppose I could avoid emitting a "NOACTION" action to the store by shifting the logic into the event handling function.

I omitted the reducers because I'm pretty sure they work - tested them out without the async logic and everything seems to work well.

Are you suggesting I break apart the two state changes into one dispatch that happens immediately and updates the application state's idea of the date, and one that is only resolved once I do the asynchronous work? I thought action creators had to return POJO..

Comment: And they do. For example requesetNewPhoto action creator could return `{ type: 'REQUEST_NEW_PHOTO', photoDate: newDate }` and in the store you get that info and update the store.  Store current state: `{ isLoading: false, currentDate: object, photoURL: 'http..' }` we call requestNewPhoto action and the new state is `{ isLoading: true, currentDate: newDate, photoURL: null }` we call newPhotoReceived and we update the store again. Of course every time the store is updated a new render should happen in you Component reflecting the new state.

Comment: And yes, async actions, are actions that dispatch sync actions as they happen. So `getNextPhoto()` is an async action that triggers two sync actions. [More info](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html).